# How to animate the Displacement of the Displace modifier

Tags: animation, modifiers

I'm trying to animate a flag but I want to avoid using Cloth or any Physics simulation. I like the deformation I get by using a Displace modifier controlled by a procedural cloud texture. If I could animate the texture so it moves across the flag I'd be happy.
Is there a way to animate the coordinates of a procedural texture used by the displacement modifier?

[image]

Blend file [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31006)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8138/599

Comment: @gandalf3 That that question is not really the same thing...

Comment: @someonewithpc It's not, but it's a similar effect. (which is why I just commented it as "related", and not a duplicate)

Comment: I had indeed read that question, and maybe could have connected the dots. But maybe someone else will find this useful

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy; Just create an Empty (While in Object Mode, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>>Empty>Plain Axis), map the displacement to the Empty's Coordinates, by selecting "Object" for the Texture Coordinates and then select the Empty for the "Object" field.

[image: Displacement Modifier]

If you then animate the Empty, the Texture will move as well, thus modifying the Displacement.