# Using cycles generated textures in the displace modifier

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, modifiers

When using cycles, it is possible to use any of the generated textures in the displace modifier. However if I chose the *Noise* texture or *Ocean* texture, there seams to be no way to edit that texture type. How do I edit the *Noise* texture or *Ocean* texture type when used as the texture in the displace modifier?

Comment: maybe related (?): http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15036/how-to-animate-the-displacement-of-the-displace-modifier

Comment: @cegaton I just read that question, but no it is not.

Comment: Note that noise doesn't have any options in BI either. You can switch over to BI for a second to edit the ocean texture, then switch back. You shouldn't need to do that though, seems like a bug to me.

Comment: This has been fixed now. https://developer.blender.org/T42262

Comment: @gandalf3 thanks, that was fast by the devs. Bug reports really do help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround seems to me is that you have bake the textures out to the uvs and then plug them into the displacement.