# True displacement in EEVEE?

Tags: animation, displacement, eevee-render-engine

I have a Blender 2.8 scene with animated true displacement. It is created using material nodes and works fine in Cycles. However, EEVEE doesn't displace my meshes truly, only normals are changed. Is it possible and how to solve the problem now or in the future?

Comment: As far as I know EEVEE doesn't support true displacement in material nodes at the moment. But maybe it will in the near future?

Comment: It is technically possible to add a Displacement Modifier to your objects, and use an animated image texture as the displacement source. This would allow you to combine the displacement effect with Eevee. However, you are limited to image sequences and movie clips. Depending on how you defined the displacement animation, you can go this route or not. If you used procedurals, consider baking the result to an image sequence, and use that as the displacement source.

Comment: In the future (after 2.80 release), there are ideas floating around about introducing a node based modifier system, see https://code.blender.org/2018/12/blender-development-fund-projects-for-first-half-2019/. This might also open up new possibilities. But all this is speculation at the moment.

Comment: @aliasguru thanks for your reply! I've already implemented animating displacement using modifier with cloud texture and an empty object with animation on it's LocRotScale – it works almost the same good as the nodes displacement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that EEVEE doesn't support true displacement in the nodes and we don't know when it will. However, it is not so difficult to find another solution.

To replace animating math and displacement nodes, I used several Displace modifiers with different textures and empty objects which have keyframes on their LocRotScale. This approach is [explained in detail here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15037/51657). I'd like also to highlight that in my case the `Direction` value was very important – displacement looked ugly before I limited it to Z axis only.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to bake the textures and use a displacement modifier as of right now, unfortunately. It will probably support true displacement in the future though.

Comment: Your approach doesn't support animation, which is done easily in Cycles displacement nodes. But I've already implemented animating displacement using modifier and an empty object with animation on it.

Comment: @AivanF. If you've solved your issue, please consider adding an answer about how you did it. It may be useful to others facing the same problem.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley done :)