# textures showing up in cycles but not in evee

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, eevee-render-engine

I have an ocean texture on a plane in a scene in blender 2.81. When using the evee render engine the ocean texture does not show up when rendering but it does in view port. In cycles it does show up in rendering however I want to render it in evee since it a bazillion times faster and doesn't have as much noise. I will have linked an image of the nodes for the ocean shader/texture and the render in cycles and evee.

Nodes:
[image]
Cycles:
[image]

evee (rendered with 1 sample):[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [True displacement in EEVEE?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128130/true-displacement-in-eevee)