# Can I use offset instead of y to map texture in displace modifier?

Tags: modifiers, constraints, displacement, texture-coordinates

I'm animating a fish to swoosh around as it moves forward using a displace modifier  (like here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58lc8sLpJzY). The problem is that I want it to go in a circle using a follow path constraint but you use offset to do the animation rather than y. The displace modifier is using the y to map the location of the fish to the cloud texture (so if it goes in a circle it would only swoosh a little bit depending how fast it is moving along the y axis).

Is there some way to map the displace modifier to offset instead of y?

Comment: Don't use global coordinates, use object. Create an empty and use it as the object that control the displacement coordinates.

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15036/how-to-animate-the-displacement-of-the-displace-modifier

Comment: Yes! that worked! Thank you!

Comment: If you found a solution, please write it on the answers section so that other users with a similar question can learn from your experience. Read:

[Can I answer my own question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)