# How to create a floating flag that isnt pinned/hooked?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I've seen how to create a flag using cloth simulation, and pinning corner vertex etc. However what Im wanting to do is have the flag fluttering in Wind, but without having the corners pinned (or at least less noticeably). It would be quite intentionally unrealistic, in that its like the flag is floating in a set place BUT the cloth is still flapping as per normal in wind.

Note: I've tried Hooks with lower Strength on corners, but they remained statically pinned. I thought each corner Hooked to an Empty, with strength of 0.2ish might make them float enough, but didnt work.

Im new to Blender so may simply be approaching wrong way.

Comment: instead of a cloth simulation use a distortion map and a displace modifier. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15036/how-to-animate-the-displacement-of-the-displace-modifier

Comment: Hi @ArtUnion, may you post your minimum working example with hooks that we can build off of?

Answer (score 0):

One way out is combination of shape keys and proportional editing applied to a subdivided plane. Subdivide a plane and make each proportional edit a separate shape key to animate later. It takes time but the wave may be regular if realism is not your goal.