# Duplicate displaced plane and have edges line up?

Tags: displacement

I have a displaced plane (shown in image 1,) which I'd like to duplicate and move next to itself to expand it into 2 tiles. However, when I do that, the edges don't line up and I can't get the individual tiles to generate new bumps while also lining up properly with the last. How might I fix this? Thank you! :)

[image: Image 1]

Comment: do you need a repetitive pattern? do you need separate objects or could you use just one big grid? in the latest case, check: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26692/how-do-i-create-repeating-patterns-with-cycles-procedural-textures

Comment: @moonboots Hi! I would like them as separate and completely new terrain tiles to specify, thank you for that though! :)

Comment: @moonboots I found an answer that worked for me and posted it if you'd like to see, thanks for helping! :)

Comment: ok, I think I may have misunderstood your question  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He he .. @MmmChezBurgerz, you beat me to it! You can put the texture into the space of any object you choose.. here, an Empty called 'Texture Space'. This answer is only for illustration..

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! I set your answer as the main answer since you included that image. :)

Comment: @MmmChezBurgerz  That's very sweet of you! It's your answer, really. The whole 'texture' mechanism is a bit of an odd legacy.. IMO.. to the user, it should look and work like shader nodes, for consistency.

Answer (score 2):

You can try duplicating the plane and then scaling it by minus 1 along whichever axis you moved it on. That way, you basically mirror the plane so the edges line up. A better way however, would probably be to just use a seamless displacement map.

Comment: Thanks for this! It did work, but like you said it just mirrors it but I'd like new terrain that still matches up. I might just try the seamless displacement map, if you wouldn't mind linking a tutorial on how to do that it'd be great please! :)

Comment: I just found an answer that works for me which I posted above, thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

I found out how to do it (with inspiration from this post: [How to animate the Displacement of the Displace modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15036/how-to-animate-the-displacement-of-the-displace-modifier))! So basically, take the tile and duplicate it next to the main tile. Now, change the displacement modifier to "Object" for the tile that you just duplicated. Set the object to the main tile and you're done. Now, as you duplicate the tiles, they (should) line up fully with the tiles around them while also generating entirely new bumps. I'm not sure if this is flawed or doesn't work in some situations, but from my experimenting it worked perfectly fine. Thank you to all those who helped! :)