# connected polygon map

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I am wondering if I have a complex model if I can get a list of connected polygons. (Or in other words if I have a texture that creeps from a point when it reaches a edge it moves onto the next polygon)

[image]

EDIT:

The uv map to the right is a diagram of what I am trying to achieve. Each of the two edges with the same letter connects. And when I draw a line off the edge of one of the UV faces it gets moved to the face that connects to it. (see edges J and K)

[image]

Comment: Welcome Catprog :) Can you share an image of your issue?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/8bwkndmmz/  The idea is I start with a point and then spread out over time from the point. (Each new color is the next stage). To do this in my program I need to know where to go when the point falls off the edge.

Comment: Sorry - don't get it. You want to seamlessly paint your object, right?

Comment: Think of it like a ripple in a pond spreading out, but over a 3d surface. And when the wave hits an edge it moves onto the next face. So on the diagram Yellow is stage 1, red stage 2 and green is stage 3.

Comment: Thanks. I think this one is related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8138/how-to-animate-noise-texture-seed Other Options are: Animated UV's with Anim All plugin: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fu8kQgclNus or simply use a Animation as Texture. Helps?

Comment: I am trying to do it outside of blender. Just building the model and UVs in blender.  When I paint on the texture and the pattern falls into the void where their is no corresponding model it instead paints it from the opposite edge. What I am trying to do in blender is build the map of the edges so it can do that.

Comment: Another way of looking at it, For every UV point how close is it to a starting point on the model.

Comment: UV mapping is a 2D image representation of your model, so it is not possible to unwrap a model without having seams. But you can rearrange your UVs and merge faces, edges and vertices to islands in the UV image editor as you like. Your issue is to arrange your UVs in a suitable way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20180/discussion-between-catprog-and-poor).

Comment: Sorry. Unfortunately I have to work and have no time to chat.