# Creating a flowing effect with Cycles noise

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I've got a Cycles noise node and would like to give it a flowing effect.

This is kind of what I mean:

[image]

I achieved this by sliding the noise distortion back and forth. The problem is that the result looks like it's moving forward, then rewinding; I'd like something that appears to continuously flow.

I can imagine that some clever texture coordinate mapping could do this. Or maybe something else?

Comment: Slide it back and forth works with most ladies but here try to only slide forward (with a driver for example) - it's procedural. That will be a continuous flow. You can also alter the Z mapping axis making a cloud-like effect, where it changes but does not move. You can combine this.

Comment: Can't really keep sliding the distortion forward, because eventually it gets too high and looks much different. Changing the z mapping wouldn't work if this was rendered on a sphere, would it?

Comment: For a sphere you need spherical mapping to make the Z be aligned with sphere normals: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45169/7777 and a Z-offsetting will work. If that will work for you I can write it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I think that'll work as long as you include the sphere mapping bit

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8138/how-to-animate-noise-texture-seed

Comment: Ahh yes cegaton's link hit the nail on the head