# Missing Open Shading Language in Cycle Renderer Check Box

Tags: cycles-render-engine, interface, osl

Was reading up some interesting answers on animating noise. Until, I found out that blender 2.75 doesn't have the same interface as shown on the image below.

Does anyone know how to turn on Open Shading Language in the cycle renderer? Following the post here [How to animate noise texture "seed"?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8138/how-to-animate-noise-texture-seed) I was not able to see the noise on screen at all. It outputs the noise as plain white.

[image: cycles osl button location in version 2.70]

Comment: OSL isn't available on GPU. If you are already set to CPU, it's possible your version of blender was compiled without it. Are you using an official build from blender.org? (btw, any particular reason for using 2.75? The latest version is currently 2.76)

Comment: Previously I had installation issue with 2.76 not registering properly so the blend thumbnail did not appear on the windows explorer. Yes I am running the official version from blender.org. I read on some other forum that OSL option was going to be available since 2.65 tho.

Comment: Yup , I can comfirm the problem was my default startup on the cycle setup was on GPU. Changing to CPU did made those Open Shading Option appear. Thanks.

Comment: Read about it in the manual but couldint find it in Blender, now I realized I needed to switch to CPU render first.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OSL isn't available on GPU. If you are already set to CPU, it's possible your version of blender was compiled without it. Are you using an official build from blender.org? (btw, any particular reason for using 2.75? The latest version is currently 2.76) – gandalf3

Comment: Now who is the joker that voted down the answer lol, wasting our time here to check.

Comment: I have set my options to CPU only on a machine that has two GTX-970s.  With CPUs off, there is no Open Shading Language available.