# How can I cycle the phase of random-based textures like noise or voronoi?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

In textures like noise or voronoi, the texture is generated through an algorithm that uses random numbers, somehow.

I want to be able to change these random numbers smoothly, so that the texture changes over time. This is demonstrated by the After Effects turbulent noise filter that has an "evolution setting". Here's the filter with the evolution changing:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: One way to fake it is by using UV coordinates for a 3D texture, then using Vector Mapping to animate the Z coordinate so that the surface is experiencing new cross-sections of the procedural.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to animate noise texture "seed"?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8138/how-to-animate-noise-texture-seed)

Comment: kinda, but it's a bit outdated. Christopher's answer did though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just set the Noise Texture (or Voronoi Texture) to 4D and manipulate the **W Input** (this "evolves" it). If you want it to move with your animation, attach a Value Node and set the value to *#frame* (makes it match the current frame). To make it transition more (visibly) smoothly, I suggest multiplying the frame value by a rather small (decimal) number to slow it down:

[image: Evolution]